# Get the same input multiple times in python tkinter?

Tags: python, input, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a program to get multiple user names and store them in a XML file. The XML part works fine, but I am having trouble with the GUI. I want to be able to ask the user how many users he wants to input, then repeat an `Entry` that number of times. How can I do that, while maintaining a `quit` function? I tried:

```
    def quitter():
        exit()
        quit()

    quitterButton = Button(master, text="Quit", command=quitter)
    mainCanvas.create_window(50, 330, window=quitterButton, tag="quitter")
    num = int(raw_input("How many users are you going to put in?"))
    for x in range(0,num):

        #Create User entry Variable
        userEnter = StringVar()
        usrVar = ""
        #Create enter box:
        userEntryBox = Entry(master, textvariable = userEnter)
        mainCanvas.create_window(250, 300, window=userEntryBox, tag="UserEnterA")

        def gotInput(self):
            usrVar = userEnter.get();
            mainCanvas.create_text(250, 330, text="User Inputted: " + usrVar, tags="0")
            mainCanvas.delete("UserEnterA")

        #Bind entry box
        userEntryBox.bind('<Key-Return>', gotInput)
        userEntryBox.wait_window(userEntryBox)

        #Create a new user element 
        newUsr= ET.Element('Member')

        #Add element to the Root
        root.append(newUsr)

        #Make a sub element Name, set name
        usrName = ET.SubElement(newUsr, 'Name')
        usrName.text = usrVar;
        ...
    tree.write('./output.xml')
```

What is the best way to go around it? I won't know the number of inputs, and I want the quit button to work at all times .

Comment: Is it necessary to use `Canvas` instead of normal geometry managers?

Comment: I am quite new to tkinter, and I only know of pack and canvas. What others are there? @kalgasnik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behavior of your program is a bit unclear for me, but I try to help.

First solution: show tkinter [askstring](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/x1164-data-entry.htm) dialog `num` times. You can break `for` loop if user press `Cancel` button. It's not exactly what you want, but it's very easy to implement:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog as simpledialog

def add_users():
    n = simpledialog.askinteger('', 'How many users are you going to put in?', initialvalue=1, minvalue=1, maxvalue=10)
    if not n: # 'Cancel'
        return
    for i in range(n):
        user = simpledialog.askstring('', 'User #%s from #%s' % (i+1, n))
        if user is None: # 'Cancel'
            return
        # Do something useful
        print(user)

root = Tk()
Button(root, text='Add users', command=add_users).pack(padx=50, pady=50)
Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).pack(pady=30)
root.mainloop()
```

Second (if you want to put entry and all new names to window with `quit` button):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog as simpledialog

class YourApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        Button(self.root, text='Quit', command=self.root.destroy).pack(pady=20)
        self.ask_button = Button(self.root, text='Add users', command=self.add_users)
        self.ask_button.pack(padx=50, pady=50)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def add_users(self):
        self.users_count = 0
        self.user_name = StringVar()
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.users_count = simpledialog.askinteger('', 'How many users are you going to put in?', initialvalue=1, minvalue=1, maxvalue=10)
        self.user_entry = Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.user_name)
        self.user_entry.pack(pady=10)
        self.user_entry.bind('<Key-Return>', self.on_new_user)
        self.user_entry.focus_set()
    def on_new_user(self, event):
        # your code
        print(self.user_name.get())
        Label(self.frame, text='User Inputted: %s' % self.user_name.get()).pack()
        self.users_count -= 1
        if not self.users_count:
            self.user_entry.destroy()
        self.user_name.set('')

YourApp()
```

---

There are three geometry managers in Tkinter: [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) (it's very similar to canvas in your case), [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) and [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm).
[Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) usually used for drawing pictures or graphs.